# Is there a way to add polyline clustering to Flutter GoogleMaps?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, zooming, polyline

There is clustering for markers such as this: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_cluster_manager, but I want to implement this with polylines or be at least to be able to view polylines at certain zoom distances.

I am drawing a lot of polylines on GoogleMaps for Flutter and I want to hide the polylines when you zoom out and redraw them when you zoom back in a certain distance. Thank you!

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I face the same problem and would like to see your solution if you have found any.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Show polylines at specific zoom?

Comment: Yes this is the intention @Zzz

Comment: So i did figure this out, although about half a year ago so I can really only give some advice. Basically, there is a function on the Googlemaps widget where If you zoom in a certain level, it will load in polyline(LatLng points). Now, If you want to load in the polylines only at a certain zoom level and what is shown on your screen, you need get the current location of the camera which is built in Google as well. Then check if the polylines are within a certain distance from your current camera location and load those in. I hope this makes sense. lmk if you have questions